# Android sending data to php and receiving issue nullpointerexception

Tags: java, php, android

Im new to android developement and I am not sure what I missing to allow the code to work. Trying to create log in application. Could there  be a problem with the way I am receiving the data or sending the data using dataoutputstream? of is there a better way that is not deprecated and complicated. Looking for the most minimalistic understandable solution.

**Do in background code**

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {


    DataOutputStream printout;
    HttpURLConnection urlConn;
    BufferedReader reader;
    URL url;
    String json;
    JSONObject jObj;


    //send POST login details to server
    try {
        url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "login.php");
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("username", params[0]);
        map.put("password", params[1]);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(HashMap.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()){
            if(sb.length() > 0){
                sb.append("&");
            }
            sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(e.getKey(), "UTF-8")).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(e.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }


        String loginDetails = sb.toString();

        printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        printout.writeBytes(loginDetails);
        printout.flush();
        printout.close();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        String result = null;
        while((result=reader.readLine())!=null) {
            sb2.append(result + '\n');
            Log.d("Results", sb2.toString());
        };

        json = result.toString();

        jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        JSONLogin = jObj.getBoolean(TAG_LOGINSTATUS);
        Log.d("LoginStatus!!!!", JSONLogin.toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("JsonConvertion", "FAILED TO CONVERT JSON");
    }


    return JSONLogin;
}
```

**Stack error**

```
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.httpkhronolog.khronolog, PID: 2459
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.httpkhronolog.khronolog.Login_Activity$checkUserDetails.doInBackground(Login_Activity.java:137)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.httpkhronolog.khronolog.Login_Activity$checkUserDetails.doInBackground(Login_Activity.java:79)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
10-18 22:43:34.169 2459-2523/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
       // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
       $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "someusername", "Password");
       // Selecting Database
       $db = mysql_select_db("khronolo_systemdb", $connection);

       $username = $_POST["username"];
       $password =  $_POST["password"];

       $query = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE password='$password' AND email='$username';";
       $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error($connection));
       $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
       if ($rows == 1) {
          $returnValue[] = array("loginStatus"=> "true");
          echo json_encode($returnValue);
       }
       else {
          $returnValue[] = array("loginStatus"=> "false");
          echo json_encode($returnValue);
       }

       mysql_close($connection);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what is there on your line no 137?

Comment: json = result.toString();

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira is the code that I am using to send the data to the php server and receiving teh result correct? I am unsure of that :(

Comment: your `while` loop is not gettting executed. so you getting null pointer exception for `result.toString()`

Comment: you should debug you code and check if you getting response back or not from server

Comment: can you debug your server? check if your request from phone is running as expected

Comment: are getting any log for Log.d("Results", sb2.toString()); this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/index.html) a **Network Library from Google**. Follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) for the same. To know more about Volley refer this [link](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-volley-library-example/)

There are also other Networking libraries like [okHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

And as of now your code is considered :

replace `json = result.toString();` with `json = sb2.toString();` at line 137

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
json = result.toString();
```

You should do

```
json = sb2.toString();
```

## Explanation

Your while loop when exits, the result will be null, so doing `result.toString()` would lead to nullpointerexception.

## Any other library

You can use GSON library to help you get/set the response values without any hurdle.

[GSON error](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwi1mZ6Rps7IAhUScY4KHXaCAqo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mkyong.com%2Fjava%2Fhow-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api%2F&usg=AFQjCNHGsLjePBwxzAlbryQ9Ga_NtmL-lA&sig2=vJd3VgVSf1ErX32qT9i_SA&bvm=bv.105454873,d.c2E)